# Magento 2 slow with logged in customer?

Tags: customer, magento2.4

**Magento 2.4.2**

When a customer is logged in, the whole store is much slower as to when a visitor is not logged in. Any idea what the reason might be? I am using the buld in FPC.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the issue with your custom module  or 3rd party extension make this slow

Comment: If none of your page seems to hit the cache check if for logged in user you have a block set as cacheable =false in one of your layout. Cacheable false prevent whole pages from caching and not only the block on which it is set. If this block is in your default layout then none of your pages get cached. This is the kind of things that happen when you want to show the customer name in the header with php .